# Efficient way of finding multiple dates per ID

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I'm trying to query my MsSQL Express database to find all CompanyID's which have multiple dates associated - when I say multiple dates, I must point out they need to be over different days.

EG

```
ID    UkDate        CompanyId
1    01/01/2015      16
2    01/01/2015      16
3    03/01/2015      18
4    05/01/2015      19
5    06/01/2015      20
6    08/01/2015      20
```

In the example above, only the rows with ComapnyID 20 would be returned because it occurred multiple times and those times were over dates (note that although companyId 16 has multiple entries, but both entries are the same date).

I'm not sure how to write the query for this using Linq. My object is already `IQueryable<T>` but, I'm not sure how to perform the query without executing the code, and then 'finishing off' the query.

I'm not near Visual Studio but the code would be (please forgive typing errors, this is from memory)

```
//First, grab unique CompanyIds as this removes those who didn't visit multiple times
var uniqueIds = (from d in this._database.MyTable 
                 select companyId).Distinct(); 


//This is the problem because on each iteration I'm re-querying the database! 
foreach(var id in uniqueIds) 
{
    var result = (from d in this._database.MyTable.OrderBy(a=>a.UkDate)
                  where d.CompanyId==id
                  select d);
   //check for nulls  

   if (result.First(a=>a.UkDate.Day) != result.Last(a => a.UkDate.Day)                      
   {
         this.AllResultsList.AddRange(results);
   } 
}
```

Whilst it works without error I don't feel the code is correct - it feels like a hack and unefficient but this was my best effort. Is there a way I could reduce the number of database requests I make and achieve the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var results = (from o in this._database.MyTable
                           group o by o.CompanyId into grouped
                           where (grouped.Max(s => s.UKDate) - grouped.Min(s => s.UKDate)).TotalDays > 0
                           select grouped.Key);
```

**Edit (by OP)**

Final result:

```
var results = (from o in this._database.MyTable
                       group o by o.CompanyId into grouped
                       where (Convert.ToDateTime(grouped.Max(s => s.UKDate)) - Convert.ToDateTime(grouped.Min(s => s.UKDate))).TotalDays > 0
                       from l in myTable
                       where l.CompanyID == grouped.Key
                       select l).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

It would be something along the lines of

```
 var results = myTable.GroupBy(x => x.CompanyID)
                .Where(g => g.GroupBy(g2 => g2.UkDate).Count()>1)
                .Select(g => g.Key);
```

Live example (albeit with LinqToObjects, but the query should work against a database just fine): http://rextester.com/FPHI53553

Answer (score 1):

A little different version:

```
var result = (from o in this._database.MyTable
              group o by o.CompanyId into grouped
              select new {
                            grouped.Key,
                            Count = grouped.Select(c => c.UkDate).Distinct().Count()
                         } into filter
                 where filter.Count > 1
                 join a in this._database.MyTable on filter.Key equals a.CompanyID
                 select new { a.CompanyID, a.UkDate}
             ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this if you want the company id and a count of the different dates:

```
from c in dataTable
group c by c.CompanyId into grouped
let count =  grouped.Select(x => x.UkDate).Distinct().Count() 
where count > 1
select new { CompanyId = grouped.Key, Count = count }
```